# Missing image on html file in android default web browser

Tags: android, html, browser, android-webview

I have a html file (contains some text and one image) stored @ /sdcard/test folder.
And image is also stored under same folder. I'am able to see the image on html file if i open html file programmatically (using a WebView).

```
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView)).loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/test/report_external.html");
```

It works. But when i go to that folder and open that html file (using default web browser of android), image file is not getting displayed. It is showing everything except image. What is the problem with default android browser to view the html file? Are there any differences between opening the file using defalut browser & WebView? 
Here is my image tag in html

```
<img src = "file:///mnt/sdcard/test/image.png"></img>
```

How could i see the image on html if it opened with default browser also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with your img-path. Try to set `src="image.png"`, it should work when both files are in the same directory. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. But what should the image src if my image is in another directory (say, /sdcard/test2). Could you please tell me?

Comment: I think the path starts from /sdcard and not from /mnt. But I'm not 100 percent sure. Try to set path to `/sdcard/test2/image.png`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the image to something else and try. might work.

Comment: Sorry guy, but this is not a serious response

Answer (score 0):

try `file:///sdcard/test/report_external.html`
instead of `file:///mnt/sdcard/test/report_external.html`
That's remove **/mnt** in your path, does it work now?